# Index creation move elastic search cluster to red

Tags: elasticsearch

I have setup an elastic search cluster with 1 master node and 1 client node, but problem is as I am creating index my cluster move to red state with 3 initializing_shards on client node, master node shards working fine.

don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: how many replicas you have configured for your index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was installation issue we have re installed elastic search and that solved our problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in question, You have only 1 master and 1 client node but you should have at least 1 data node to store at least primary shards.

Comment: both nodes are data node also

Comment: do you know what was the exact issue? Could you share here how did you resolved(re-installing elasticsearch not making sense for me) it?

Comment: I don't know the exact issue as  there was nothing in the log, may be we have messed up some setting earlier as we were trying to setup cluster